When to use insChild versus render to display a backdraftjs component
I can make a component display on the page using render or using insChild. Is one preferable?

insChild should be used whenever possible; the only time global render is useful is when rendering the top-level Component instance (or, in rare cases, instances, plural) in, broadly speaking, the "application" offered by the document.
details
Recall a Component instance is an abstraction that bridges the gap between a "logical" thing and a physical thing.
The logical thing may be something simple like a button with various dynamic state that can be pressed. Or may be quite complex, like a 1,000,000 cell grid with dynamically updating content.
The physical thing is always a dom tree. E.g.,  a <button> node that contains an <img> node and a couple of <span> nodes and the content and class attributes of those nodes are mutated as the logical state of the button mutates. Or, the really interesting grid case where the logical state always has all 1,000,000 cells, but the physical state only contains enough dom nodes to fill the viewport.
In all cases, as a Component instance is created, lives, and is eventually destroyed, the following things always happen:

The javascript class instance is created.
The dom tree associated with that instance is created.
That dom tree is inserted into the document.
That dom tree is removed from the document.
That dom tree is destroyed.
The javascript class instance is destroyed.

Remember, a Component instance can exist perfectly fine while not being rendered and attached to the document, and, therefore, having no physical embodiment. And further, a component instance may move back and forth between states 2, 3, and 4.
When the Component instance is managed as a child of another Component instance, all of the life cycle management methods are applied automatically. On the other hand, when a Component instance is rendered by global render and then inserted/removed into/from the document tree manually, the life cycle management methods involving attaching to the document must be  applied explicitly...which is painful and error-prone.
The typical backdraft pattern is to have only a few--usually one--top level Component instance into which children Component instances are inserted and deleted...then all the life cycle management is automatic and everything "Just Works".

Thanks. What I saw specifically was that, using render(), the component's onMutateAttachedToDoc didn't work right; the single "attached" arg was always false.
